# How to pass data to view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I wrote a function in controller

```
class GPromoCode extends Controller {
    public function generatePromoCode() {
        $length = 8;
        $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $string = '';    
        $prefix ='KM';
        for ($p = 0; $p < $length ; $p++) {
            $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)- 1)];
        }
        return $prefix.$string;
    }
}
```

In view blade template, how to pass string to textbox through $coupon
eg: {{ $coupon }}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting value outside of inputbox then try like this  `<input type="text" value = "{{ $coupon }}"`

Comment: good job you pushed a button called Ask question and you posted what?

Comment: where do you instantiate your view ?

Comment: provide the controller method

Comment: I try  fix : 
$coupon = $prefix.$string;
 return View('coupon')->with('coupon' , $coupon ); but the result 
Undefined variable: coupon

Comment: Your coupon code should be running under the same controller when you press submit not on it's own one.

Comment: I forget adding additional routes . @madalinivascu, you guess true.i'm just a newbie.Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data in view file from controller like this way :

```
public function generatePromoCode() {
        $length = 8;
        $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $string = '';    
        $prefix ='KM';
        for ($p = 0; $p < $length ; $p++) {
            $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)- 1)];
        }
        return view('view_file_name',['string'=>$string,'prefix'=>$prefix]);
    }
```

And simply you can get above both variable in your view file like this:

```
{{$prefix}}
{{$string}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function generatePromoCode()
        {
        $length = 8;
        $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $string = '';    
        $prefix ='KM';
            for ($p = 0; $p < $length ; $p++) {
                $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)- 1)];
                }
        $coupon = $prefix.''.$string;

        return View('coupon',compact('coupon')); 
        }


<input type="text" value = "{{$coupon}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class GPromoCode extends Controller
{
    //generate promote code
    public function generatePromoCode()
    {
    $length = 8;
    $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $string = '';    
    $prefix ='KM';
        for ($p = 0; $p < $length ; $p++) {
            $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)- 1)];
            }
          $data = $prefix.$string;
         return View('your_view_page_name',compact('data')); 
    }

}

<input type="text" value = "{{$data}}">
```